Is the call (&) operator less vulnerable to code injection attacks than Invoke-Expression?
A PowerShell function needs to run a .exe whose location is not known at design-time because it's part of a NuGet package. If I run it using Invoke-Expression then PSScriptAnalyzer raises a warning telling me to find an alternative method, however if I run it using & then I get no warning.
This is the function, which is part of a module for running unit tests and generating a code coverage report on a machine where the installed IDE does not support code coverage (e.g. Visual Studio Community Edition).
function Invoke-ReportGenerator {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$testProjectFolder,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$testProjectName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$assemblyUnderTest,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$coverageXmlFilename,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$reportGeneratorPath
    )

    if ([System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($coverageXmlFilename)) {
        $coverageXmlFilename = "coverage.opencover.xml";
    }

    $absoluteOutputPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($testProjectFolder, "CodeCoverage");
    $absoluteInputPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($testProjectFolder, $coverageXmlFilename);
    $argumentArray = @(
        "-reports:$absoluteInputPath",
        "-targetDir:$absoluteOutputPath",
        "-title:$testProjectName",
        "-assemblyFilters:$assemblyUnderTest"
    );
    if ([System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($reportGeneratorPath)) {
        $reportGeneratorPath = "$env:USERPROFILE\.nuget\packages\reportgenerator\5.2.4\tools\net6.0\reportgenerator.exe ";
    }

    $reportGeneratorCommand = "$reportGeneratorPath $argumentArray";
    Invoke-Expression $reportGeneratorCommand;
}

This is the warning raised by PSScriptAnalyzer
Invoke-Expression is used. Please remove Invoke-Expression from script and find other options instead.

Microsoft docs say to Avoid using Invoke-Expression

Carefully consider the security implications. When a string from an untrusted source such as user input is passed directly to Invoke-Expression, arbitrary commands can be executed. Always consider a different, more robust and secure solution first.

If I change the line
Invoke-Expression $reportGeneratorCommand;

to
& $reportGeneratorCommand;

Then the warning goes away. But surely this is just as vulnerable to a code injection attack as Invoke-Expression? What am I missing?
Edit: replacing the last 2 lines of the function with & $reportGeneratorPath @argumentArray as suggested by @MathiasRJessen simplifies the function slightly, but I believe still leaves it vulnerable.

Back when I was first learning PowerShell, I asked a related question and received this answer.

You'll want to use it like this instead: & $reportGeneratorPath @argumentArray

The difference between Invoke-Expression and the invocation operators (& and .) is structured syntax.
Unlike Invoke-Expression, the operators accept the target command and the arguments separately, using the following syntax:
<op> [<module-spec>] <target-command> [arguments...]

... and as suggested in the comments, you should use them in conjunction with splatting, like this:
& $command @arguments


but I believe still leaves it vulnerable.

Perhaps the following example will shake your beliefs.
Let's start by defining a target command and some user-suplied arguments including an attempted command injection:
$command = 'Write-Host'
$arguments = @(
  'Legitimate message'
  ';'
  'Write-Host'
  'malware'
)

Let's see what happens when we construct a string and pass it off to Invoke-Expression like you've been doing so far:
PS ~> $expression = "$command $arguments"
PS ~> Invoke-Expression $expression
Legitimate message
malware

As you can see, Invoke-Expression happily evaluated both the target command and the Write-Host malware command tacked at the end.
Let's try the same with an invocation operator:
PS ~> & $command @arguments
Legitimate message ; Write-Host malware

As you see here, all arguments were passed as just that - no invocation of any additional commands injected by the caller.

This example illustrates the difference between & and Invoke-Expression brilliantly and clearly. Thank you for helping this PowerShell newbie to understand this subtlety. Answer accepted and upvoted and now I'm going to look at some other functions where I've replaced Invoke-Expression with & to make sure I've done it correctly.
